# Azure download task in SSIS fails on 400 error

Tags: azure, csv, ssis, download

I am working in Visual Studios 2019, on SSIS 2019 and SQL Server 2019.
My goal is to download a .csv file from an Azure Blob, then process it and load it into a table in our database.  Even though when testing the connection in the connection manager editor I get a "successful" result, when running the actual download task that uses that connection manager, I get 400 (Bad Request) error.

I have recreated the connection manager, still no luck. I have also verified that there are no spelling issues between the SSIS blob container field and the real blob container in azure.  The storage account name and blob container name are all lower case.  I'm at a loss here, and any help would be appreciated.  The fact that the connection manager itself returns "Successful" when I test the connection leads me to believe that the problem is in the Download task itself, but there's really not much to those things.  I know the Blob Container field is accurate.

[image: error code]

[image: the "Test Connection" button returns successful!]

Answer (score 2):

Else then Changing TLS Version we need toadd SchUseStrongCrypto registery key to the machine. For local machine, you only need to execute below command to add this registery key:

1. reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SchUseStrongCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /reg:64 -F
2. reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SchUseStrongCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /reg:32 -F

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles here, I've found out my issue. It was actually the Storage Account itself.  It was set to Minumum TLS Version = 1.2 (in the Configuration tab).  I needed to set this to 1.0, and my SSIS Azure Download task worked with no problem.

I personally don't know the ramifications of this change, but all the other storage accounts in my company are set to 1.0, so I feel fine doing it.